# Inserting a line in the beginning of a file using sed in HP-UX

Tags: shell, unix, sed, insert, hp-ux

I am trying to insert a line in the beginning of a file using sed.
I tried below commands :

`sed -i '1s/^/LINE TO INSERT\n/' test.txt`
`sed: illegal option -- i` --> Error thrown

`sed '1i/^/LINE TO INSERT\n/' test.txt`
`sed: Function 1i/^/LINE TO INSERT\n/ cannot be parsed.`   --> Error thrown

Both the ways came out to be failed. 
Any possible solution to it ? I am using `ksh` script on HP-UX.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you `echo "LINE TO INSERT" > tmp_file.txt` then `cat test.txt >> tmp_file.txt` and finally `mv tmp_file.txt test.txt`?

Answer (score 3):

How about good old `ed`?

```
printf '%s\n' 1i 'LINE TO INSERT' . w | ed -s file
```

`printf` is used to send each command to `ed` on a separate line.

Alternatively, if you're terrified of `ed` like me, you can just use a temporary file, as suggested in the comments:

```
echo 'LINE TO INSERT' > tmp && cat tmp test > new && mv new test && rm tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo: you're missing the closing apostrophe from your 1st command. Otherwise it's fine. I.e.:

You have this: `sed -i '1s/^/... test.txt`

But you need this: `sed -i '1s/^/...' test.txt`

Putting all together: `sed -i '1s/^/LINE TO INSERT\n/' test.txt`

**Update**: if -i is not supported, then you can use a temporary file:

```
sed '1s/^/LINE TO INSERT\n/' test.txt > /tmp/test.txt.tmp
mv /tmp/test.txt.tmp test.txt
```

Comment: The version of `sed` on this system is very unlikely to support `-i`, so this won't help.

Comment: Well ,last one worked , but it is appending 'n' after the line. How to avoid it ? Thanks

Comment: I can only give suggestions since I have different environment. According to this page: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1184966 you could replace `\n` with `^M` in your sed command: `sed '1s/^/LINE TO INSERT^M/' ...`